# JQuery not loading properly when placing order

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento2

Something is not loading correctly when this js is called and I can't figure out what. It isn't sending the information properly, sometimes it clears the cc checkout fields, sometimes it is just stuck in loading.

It appeared to be working on the development site but now thats its been moved to a live site, it just doesn't want to work anymore.

Would the switch from http to https be triggering this?

```
 * @param {jQuery} element - Comment holder
     */
    (function lookup(element) {
        var iframeHostName;

        // prevent cross origin iframe content reading
        if ($(element).prop('tagName') === 'IFRAME') {
            iframeHostName = $('<a>').prop('href', $(element).prop('src'))
                                         .prop('hostname');

            if (window.location.hostname !== iframeHostName) {
                return [];
            }
        }

        $(element).contents().each(function (index, el) {
            switch (el.nodeType) {
                case 1: // ELEMENT_NODE
                    lookup(el);
                    break;

                case 8: // COMMENT_NODE
                    elements.push(el);
                    break;

                case 9: // DOCUMENT_NODE
                    lookup($(el).find('body'));
                    break;
            }
        });
    })(this);

    return elements;
};
```

Comment: Are you trying to load http resources onto an https site?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  It looks like your example includes more code than is necessary to exhibit the problem.  Please try whittling it down to the minimal code that doesn't work.  (Often this helps find the problem!)  For more info, see [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Taplar I'm getting some Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with / cross-origin frame issues with page-cache.js and jquery.js

Comment: If your site has an iframe on it that does not match the protocol://domain:port of the page that hosts it, then you will run into XSS errors.  All three of those parts of the url must match to not hit XSS.  Verify that they match.

Comment: @Taplar - it shows me in the console where it is having the issue, I have changed to show the code where It is telling me the issues are in each .js file.